# MutationObserver on el.getBoundingClientRect() to detect element position on screen

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm trying to detect a DOM element screen position change without polling or using events like `onscroll` and so on. `MutationObserver` would do the trick, but it seems that it won't work for methods (like getBoundingClientRect() for example).

Is that accurate? If not, how do I use MutationObserver to detect clientRect changes?

Example: https://codepen.io/Darksoulsong/pen/rwOQLo

Add new boxes, scroll the viewport, add some more and note that the rect values don't get updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "position change"?

Comment: The element position on screen. In this case, `element.getBoundingClientRect().left`

Comment: MutationObserver detects changes in DOM nodes/attributes, so if there are none it won't work, naturally. In that case use ResizeObserver and IntersectionObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm Where is `ResizeObserver` documented?

Comment: @guest271314 is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

seems by it's very nature, getBoudingClientRect is not supported, did you find other solutions? thanks

Comment: @darksoulsong Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: @HarshalPatil I didn't. So I had to find a workaround and write a polling function to make it work as I expected at the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An event or observer for changes to getBoundingClientRect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251082/an-event-or-observer-for-changes-to-getboundingclientrect)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251082 can be the canonical duplicate, as it has the most thought in the couple answers. 40251082 needs more work though.