# IntersectionObserver and position: absolute

Tags: javascript, css-position, intersection-observer

IntersectionObserver does not seem to work when the observed element has `position: absolute` and the root is not the
viewport.

Am I missing something here?

(Try removing the `position: absolute` to see the expected result.)

```js
let intersectionRoot = document.getElementById("intersectionRoot");
let observedElement = document.getElementById("observedElement");
let shifted = false; // Internal for the example

let interSectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries, observer) => {
        console.log(entries[0].isIntersecting)
    },
    { root: intersectionRoot }
);
interSectionObserver.observe(observedElement);

window.setInterval(
    () => {
        observedElement.classList.toggle("shifted")
    },
    1000
)
```

```css
#intersectionRoot {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#observedElement {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.shifted {
    transform: translate3d(110px, 0, 0)
}
```

```html
<div id="intersectionRoot">
    <div id="observedElement" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if i'm missing something, what if you add `position: relative` to `#intersectionRoot` ? Is that the expected behavior? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/faj7onmc/)

Comment: Yeah that seems to do it. Is there a reasonable explanation for why IntersectionObserver would work like this?

Comment: I guess it's because if you don't explicitly set `position: relative` to the root element its children (in this case `observedElement`) refers to the `body`. From the [docs](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#intersection-observer-interface): `An IntersectionObserver with a non-null root is referred to as an explicit root observer, and it can observe any target Element that is a descendant of the root in the containing block chain.`

Comment: Ohh that's tricky. It would be alot easier to understand if the visual intersection was what mattered. Thanks anyway, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `position: relative` to the root element. Here's an updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/faj7onmc/).

If you don't explicitly set `position: relative` to the root element its children (in this case `observedElement`) refers to the `body`. From the [IntersectionObserver docs](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#intersection-observer-interface): `An IntersectionObserver with a non-null root is referred to as an explicit root observer, and it can observe any target Element that is a descendant of the root in the containing block chain.`